# MAUI: Header in CollectionView not displayed when layout is inserted

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to show a header in a CollectionView with this code (which im sure would work in Xamarin)

```xml
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Multiple"
                SelectionChanged="collectionview_coll_skills_SelectionChanged"
                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                EmptyView="{x:Static res:Strings.LaedtSKills}"
                Grid.Row="0"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" x:Name="collectionview_coll_skills">
                <CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ContentView>
                                  <Label Text="Hi mom"/>
                            </ContentView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
```

The text "hi mom" is just not shown at all.

However, if I insert the text directly into the property (e.g. Header="hi mom"), it gets displayed but then no layouting is possible.

Has anyone already found a fix or workaround for this?

Comment: If you just want to show a header, that you can style, you can use <CollectionView.Header>
       <Label Text="Hi mom" />
</CollectionView.Header>

Comment: That did totally work. Just removing all the wrappings inside contentviews and datatemplates..

Comment: Note that nowhere did you specify `Header`. `HeaderTemplate` is just a template. It doesn't apply unless you tell it to. If you added `Header="{Binding .}"` to your original code, it would probably have worked. Overkill for your purpose, but useful to know. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/226760/collectionview-headertemplate-and-emptyviewtemplat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in my comment you can just use the `Header` of the `CollectionView`
You can style it as needed. More Info [Microsoft Header/Footer resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout?view=net-maui-7.0#headers-and-footers)

```
<CollectionView.Header> 
    <Label Text="Hi mom" /> 
</CollectionView.Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewCell is available for ListView but not for CollectionView.
I run into the same problem when I updated from a ListView to a CollectionView.
[Klick for an example. Do not use ViewCell for CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQb2z.png)

Comment: Can you please copy the code into the answer instead of sharing the screenshot? That way if the img gets taken down the answer remains useful.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem a while ago. The problem is, when we assign a value to the "**EmptyView**" property as a *template, the header template in the collectionview gets corrupted*. You can try it in Android environment.

[example of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuiJP.png)

[With (Set emptyview property)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmFvO.png)

[Without(not set emptyview property)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2nA6.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/13138364)

Comment: Please translate your code from an image into a [code block]. Images of code are not helpful for the reasons tdy's link explains.